# getting a substring out of a item in yahoo pipes

Tags: xml, regex, json, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

following situation:

```
item.
   content => "This is a 48593 test"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => "This is a 48593 test 3255252"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => "This 35542 is a 48593 test"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => "i havent exactly 5 digits 34567654"
   title => "the title"
```

this is my current item in the console of pipes

no i want to replace "content" with "the last match of a number that has exactly 5 digits. 
wanted result:

```
item.
   content => "48593"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => "48593"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => "48593"
   title => "the title"

item.
   content => ""
   title => "the title"
```

is there a way to do this in pypes 2?

please comment if something is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex module like this:

In item.content replace `(.*)` with `X $1`

In item.content replace `.*\b(\d{5})\b.*` with `$1`

In item.content replace `X .*` with nothing (leave field empty)

[Here's an example pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/arendvrcom/stackoverflowquestion5035497)

**Some Explanations**

- `\d{5}` finds exactly five digits
- `\b` word boundaries, so that numbers with more digits are not found
- the `X`  at the beginning marks strings where the regular expression doesn't match to delete them afterwards
- finding the last number and not the first is the default behavior. Because `*` is a greedy operator.

Comment: i'm runnning into a little issue. i cannot access my content with the regex module. can you please take a look at http://bit.ly/eojb9J . my content to replace is in item.content.content

Answer (score 0):

sorry , i don't know anything else than Python

but as your problem interested me and that regexes are more or less the same in all the langages, I propose my solution in Python

```
import re

pat = re.compile("(?:.*((?<!\d)(?:\d{5})(?!\d))|\Z).*")

gh = ("This is a 48593 test",
      "This is a 48593 test 3255252",
      "This 35542 is a 48593 test",
      "i havent exactly 5 digits 34567654")

for x in gh:
    print x
    print 'AAA'+pat.search(x).groups("")[0]+'ZZZ'
    print
```

results

```
This is a 48593 test
AAA48593ZZZ

This is a 48593 test 3255252
AAA48593ZZZ

This 35542 is a 48593 test
AAA48593ZZZ

i havent exactly 5 digits 34567654
AAAZZZ
```

The 'AAA' and 'ZZZ' have no other utility to show that the 4th result gives ""

The **""** in **groups("")** gives the default value **""** when there is no match

Otherwise the 4th result would be **None** :

```
import re

pat = re.compile("(?:.*((?<!\d)(?:\d{5})(?!\d))|\Z).*")

gh = ("This is a 48593 test",
      "This is a 48593 test 3255252",
      "This 35542 is a 48593 test",
      "i havent exactly 5 digits 34567654")

for x in gh:
    print x
    print pat.search(x).groups()[0]
    print
```

results in

```
This is a 48593 test
48593

This is a 48593 test 3255252
48593

This 35542 is a 48593 test
48593

i havent exactly 5 digits 34567654
None
```